# Can I make a quick action for run a txt

Tags: text

on run {input, parameters}
tell application "Finder"
set selection to make new file at (get insertion location)
end tell
return input
end run

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9QSL.png)

Answer (score 0):

the error seems to be saying that it can't find the file with the name ""; here some links with examples that might help you debug further: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-SW3

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/323567/cant-get-alias

I would also suggest checking the Applescript doc - specifically the examples in the 'Working with Aliases' section: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW28